# How to prepare and insert data from a file into Mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, database, bulkinsert

I have this data on an XLS file. 
The XLS file is a mess with a lot of data that I don't need. I will clean the file and I can re-arrange it.

I have something like this:

```
Level  - Code  - Description
 1        A       'foo foo'
 2       12331    'bar bar'
 3       13123    'bla bla'
 4       21321    'plim bar'
 5       12111    'foo plim'
 5       12111    'plim bla'
 5       12111    'bla plim'
 1        B       'bla bar'
 n        ...      ...
```

The **Level** defines the hierarchy position, like 1 is a top hierarchy. 5 is the lowest.

I will make use of the Adjacency List Model to store this information. 
So I believe I will have to store it like this:

```
id - description - parent_id
 1    'foo foo'      NULL
 2    'bar bar'       1
 3    'bla bla'       2
 4    'plim bar'      3
 5    'foo plim'      4
 6    'plim bla'      4
 7    'bla plim'      4
 8    'bla bar'      NULL
 n     ...            ...
```

What is the best (fastest, easiest) method to insert this information like this? 
Should I convert to a CSV? How should I format the XLS file so that I can insert this information by maintaining the hierarchy ?

There are 9000 lines in the XLS file, and I would love to avoid doing this one by one!

**What methods should we consider in order to successfully import this data ?**

**Update:**
I have this mysqlworkbench software... I'm on Ubuntu and all opensource here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LOAD` command, with csv-like data, if that's at all possible.

Here's an example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path-to-your-data-file'
INTO TABLE <your-table>
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2,..., coln)
;
```

where `IGNORE 1 LINES` means your column headings in the data file will be ignored, and  `(col1, col2,..., coln)` are the database columns to use.

You have lots of other options available to you (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) and `LOAD` is supposedly up to 20 times faster then `INSERT` for large data loads (according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html).

Comment: So I have to first convert the xls into a csv file, and on that process I should choose \t and \n and '' somewhere ? Lire Office Calc should do this... ?

Comment: if you have MySQL 5.5, you can use LOAD XML (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html). Otherwise you'll have to transform the data yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) to do the importing, the free version will do just fine.

Comment: I use mysqlworkbench perhaps it does the same... I confess and I haven't looked at it yet...

Comment: @mem , i have tried to use mysqlbench ,it just doesn't work for me , but navicat has saved my life numerous times , give it a try :)